# Target jQuery file in gulp no matter what version it has

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

At the moment I have following task to concatenate and minify my javascript files into one:

```
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    jsPath + 'libraries/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'
    jsPath + 'libraries/*.js',
    jsPath + 'app.js'
  ])
  .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(jsPath))
});
```

I need to ensure jQuery is included first before any libraries (as I have jQuery plugins in there) so I need to target it first, however When I upgrade to the latest version, I also need to change version number in gulpfile, therefore I wanted to see if there is a way to target a file that contains `jquery-2` in its filename (not just jquery, as some plugins use this in their names as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [gulp-order](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order) plugin for your purpose. For the versioning it's better to keep file with stable name, e.g. `jquery-latest.js`, but my recommendation is to not download and keep libraries by yourself, but use bower instead for dependency management, it will solve your versioning problem too. Good luck :)